# Cant get animation to ease

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to animate an inner Div object... but I can't get easing to work..

Here is the fiddle:

```
$(".trigger").hover(function(){
$(".content").animate(
            { left: 0 }, {
                duration: 'slow',
                easing: 'easeOutBounce'
            });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/auvitijuana/a2cuL4mf/13/

I know everything is OK, but there is something I'm missing.

Comment: are you using jquery-ui?

Comment: jquery 2.1.0 selected on the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need javaScript to animate Use CSS instead it's better performance wise

```
.trigger
{
    transition: all 0.75s ease-in-out;
}

.trigger:hover
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, yes it works on CSS, but I need the code to work cause I'm puzzled by the code not working

Answer (score 1):

You have to add jQuery.easing plugin.
http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/